# Parâmetro do Jasper não está passando o valor para a query

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, relatório, jaspersoft-studio

O data set está configurado e os parâmetros também dentro da aplicação, mas não está funcionando e nem dentro do "emulador" do jasper. 
 O campo pede o valor, após colocá-lo ele executa e traz a página em branco, mas isso se eu digitar um valor válido, caso seja inválido há erro na busca.

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Poderia detalhar como está a consulta no seu relatório e qual o valor está sendo passado, pode ser algum problema em como está o parâmetro, se está `$P{parametro}` ou `$P!{parametro}`. Sugiro a leitura do link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-parameters-queries